# Execute a LS through ssh and store it into a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to run an ssh command to get the path on a remote machine in order to get the last file and store it into a variable. This is what I've made so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
database="devdatabase";
echo "Executing Restore Database: '$database'"
filetodump=ssh user@myvirtualmysqlmachine.com 'bash -s'$(ls -1t -d /var/MySQLBackups/prod_mysql/* | grep dump | head -n 1)
echo "This is to test that the srcipt works: '$filetodump'"
```

How can i get the `$filetodump` variable?

Comment: Not really since in that situation the command is not run over ssh. I'm running an SSH in order to get a path then display this path with echo

Comment: What's the difference? `ssh` is still a command. And its output can be capture to a variable in the same way. Have you tried it?

Comment: If we want to have the result of a command, we must put the command between $ (cmd) or `cmd`